# jquery.countdown.js Doesn't Count Down in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

We have a countdown on www.follettchallenge.com.

Uses jQuery.js, version 1.7 and jquery.countdown.js version 1.6.1 from http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Been trying for hours to figure out why this doesn't count down in Chrome, but it works fine in IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox, and on an Android device. The demo from keith-wood.name works fine in Chrome, so it's definitely something on our end.

Any thoughts on what we might try?  I've already tried updating to the latest version of jQuery with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Works on chrome here : http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html Can you make a small example of your usage?

Comment: http://www.follettchallenge.com/ works on my chrome as well showing 16 days and counting down

Comment: http://www.follettchallenge.com/ works fine on my Chrome too.

Comment: Works here too, both on Win8 and Linux

Comment: On Win7 and it doesn't work. Another user sees the same thing. The numbers are accurate to when the page loads, but they don't count down.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, js countdown didn't work in Chrome only.

Updating to version 1.6.2 fixed the problem

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html